# Define groups of row by logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a unique scenario to which i can't find a solution, so i thought to ask the experts :)

I have a query that returns a course syllabus, which each row represent a day of training. You can see in the picture below that there are rest days in the middle of the training

I can't find a way to group the each consecutive training days

Please see screenshot below detailed the rows and what i want to achieve

**I am using MS-SQL 2014**

Here is a Fiddle with the data i have and the expected results
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bfa4/1)

[image]

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Comment: 1) Mention the database/version; 2) Instead of image, paste `text` so we can use it; 3) Do you need to group based on consecutive days? If yes, what do you want to do after the grouping? Give expected result

Comment: I have updated the question added DB version and SQL Fiddle that you can work with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is a difference of `row_number()`.  The following identifies each consecutive group with a number:

```
select td.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by dateadd(day, - seqnum, DayOfTraining)) as grpnum
from (select td.*,
             row_number() over (order by DayOfTraining) as seqnum
      from TrainingDays td
     ) td;
```

The key idea is that subtracting a sequence from consecutive days produces a constant for those days.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bfa4/5) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Brilliant. I wrapped my head around for more than an hour but still couldn't manage it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After many hit and trials, this is the closest I could come up with

http://rextester.com/ECBQ88563

The problem here is that if last row belongs to another group, it will still use it with previous group. So in your sample if you change last date from 19 to 20, the output will still be the same. May be with another condition we can eliminate it. Other than that this should work.

```
SELECT DayOfTraining1,
       dense_rank() over (ORDER BY grp_dt) AS grp
FROM
  (SELECT DayOfTraining1,
          min(DayOfTraining) AS grp_dt
   FROM
     (SELECT trng.DayOfTraining AS DayOfTraining1,
             dd.DayOfTraining
      FROM trng
      CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT d.*
         FROM
           (SELECT trng.*,
                   lag (DayOfTraining,1) OVER (
                                               ORDER BY DayOfTraining) AS nxt_DayOfTraining,
                   lead (DayOfTraining,1) OVER (
                                                ORDER BY DayOfTraining) AS prev_DayOfTraining,
                   datediff(DAY, lag (DayOfTraining,1) OVER (
                                                             ORDER BY DayOfTraining), DayOfTraining) AS ddf
            FROM trng
            ) d
         WHERE d.ddf <> 1
           OR prev_DayOfTraining IS NULL 
        ) dd
      WHERE trng.DayOfTraining <= dd.DayOfTraining 
      ) t
   GROUP BY DayOfTraining1
   ) t1;
```

Explanation: The inner query `d` is using `lag` and `lead` functions to capture previous and next rows values. Then we are taking the days difference and using and capturing dates where difference is not 1. These are the dates where group should switch. Use a derived table dd for the same.

Now cross join this with main table and use aggregate function to determine the continuous groups (took me many hit and trials) to achieve this.

Then use `dense_rank` function on it to get the group.